# How to retrieve key value pair within listed dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as a key value pairs, where I want to access the data of each dict by key:

sample data:

```
['"imageUrl":"/images/4.jpg"', '"number":"04047122"', '"name":"test"',...
```

real data

```
>>> data
['"imageUrl":"/images/products/klein/04047122_k.jpg"', '"art":"04047122"', '"productId":"170336"'; } } }) ']
```

This unfortunatelly does not work:

```
re.findall(r'(?:number\(\{)(.*)', data)[0].split(',')
```

How can I retrieve the values by name e.g. `data['number']` ?

Comment: It looks like you have a list of strings, each of which shows a key:value pair.  Why not convert it into an actual dict?

Comment: `'"imageUrl":"/images/4.jpg"'` is a string, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

For a more robust solution, since each string in the input list is a valid line of CSV, delimited by a colon, you can use `csv.reader` to parse the list and then pass the resulting sequence of key-value pairs to the `dict` constructor to build a dict:

```
import csv
lst = ['"imageUrl":"/images/4.jpg"', '"number":"04047122"', '"name":"test"']
data = dict(csv.reader(lst, delimiter=':'))
```

You can then access `data['number']` as desired.

Comment: I am getting a "  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #31 has length 3; 2 is required".

Comment: Apparently some strings in your input list have more than 2 colon-delimited items. Please update your question with a sample of the actual input that can reproduce the error if you need help fixing it.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I updated my question and included real data.

Comment: What kind of source produces such an input? The strings towards the end of the updated sample of input list are simply incomplete code snippets that are nowhere close to being key-value pairs as you describe. You need to fix the logics of whichever source such data come from instead in this case.

Comment: Well not a good one apparently. I managed to get my result via regex: re.findall('.*(?:"name":")(.*?)"\'', d)[0]
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your `data` to a *real* dictionary:

```
data = ['"imageUrl":"/images/4.jpg"', '"number":"04047122"', '"name":"test"']
data_dict = dict([x.replace('"','').split(":") for x in data])
```

and then you will be able to access your keys:

```
print(data_dict["number"]) # output: 04047122
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the strings within the keys and values do not contain `"` or `:` themselves.

Comment: I am getting a "  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #9 has length 1; 2 is required"

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string list to an actual dictionary easily:

```
>>> ls = ['"imageUrl":"/images/4.jpg"', '"number":"04047122"', '"name":"test"']
>>> data = dict(elem.replace('"', '').split(':') for elem in ls)
>>> data
{'imageUrl': '/images/4.jpg', 'number': '04047122', 'name': 'test'}
>>> data['number']
'04047122'
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the strings within the keys and values do not contain `"` or `:` themselves.